# PHP shopping cart update not working

Tags: php, mysql

New guy here! I am building a custom shopping cart driven by mysql and I am trying to update my cart item by item in terms of quantity. It seems that I am doing something wrong because when I try to update the quantity it only update the first item. I am posting the code below. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<form method='post'>
        <input type='hidden' name='user' value='$username'>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='id[$data[id_product]]' value='$data[id_product]'>
        <input class='cart_quantity_input' type='number' name='quantity[$data[id_product]]' min='1' value='$data[qty_product]' autocomplete='off' size='2'>
```

Above is my input.

```
function update_cart() {
    foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) {
    $item_id= $id;
    $user=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'][$key];
    $sql2 = "update cart set qty_product='$quantity' where id_shopper='$user' AND id_product='$id'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die ("Error in query: $result2");
    $i++;
}
```

And the function.

What is going wrong here?Thanks.

Comment: when you are calling update_cart()...

Comment: after form is submited

Comment: Are you sure that your inputs return the correct value ?

Comment: Sure, like i said before it only update the first item of array, any idea?

Comment: @raveenanigam any idea?

Comment: try to echo the sql query...

Comment: please stop using mysql_* functions they are deprecated. there is no need for $i++ in your function and i think your form part is not getting updated value='$data[id_product]' might be concatenation issue